# The add node that I need doesn't have the same options as the one that appears to me

Tags: node-editor

I don't manage to get this node with this specific options. The one I get using the node *Math* doesn't have the option image and only has value options.

[image: The node that I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a *Mix* node set to *Add*. Presumably what you currently have is a *Math* node set to *Add*.